# Reading parameters from RDL file from web UI - SSRS

Tags: dynamic, rdl, ssrs-2008-r2, reportparameter

I have a set of reports and I need to use only a single UI for the parameter section for all the reports, that is the intention was for the report parameters layout screen to read the parameters collection in the reports RDL file and dynamically create the screen.

So that:

- There is only one parameters screen (and not one per report)
- Any parameter changes to the RDL file will be reflected immediately
  an will not require a development change to the parameter screen

Please let me know is there a solution for this. Or I have to use separate parameter UI for each report.